# Mongo Atlas Search index in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-atlas-search

I already have a Docker Mongo image in my NodeJs service. I implement the acceptance test using the Docker Mongo image. But now, I start to use Atlas Search as well and I want to create Atlas Search index on my Mongo Docker. I did search on the documentation but couldn't find a way. Do you have any idea how can I create an index for my local environment with docker? Otherwise I get this error `caused by MongoServerError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$search'`

Comment: Atlas search is a commercial offering from Mongo. It's an elasticsearch instance pulling data from mongodb collections. It is not available in self-hosted mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Atlas cli to connect to a test database and run your queries to atlas.

Take a look to this guide:

https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/local-development-mongodb-atlas-cli-docker/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Atlas CLI is the only option at this time. Please see from MongoDB's page, [Create a Local Atlas Deployment](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cli/stable/atlas-cli-deploy-local/)

Looks like there is also a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mongodb/atlas) for the CLI as well if you choose.